# I just wondering if the peripherals like DMA, PWM and such, are all accessible from user-space

Tags: hardware, driver, software-development

I managed to access `GPIO` registers according to the [datasheet](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/processors.html#bcm2835) by `mmap`ing the `peripherals-base-address` provided from `"/proc/device-tree/soc/ranges"`and made my own user-space library and just wondering if this is applicable for any other peripheral registers like these from DMA, PWM, TIMER, INTERRUPTS and such. Can I access them the same way as the GPIO registers and create a user-space library to manage these peripherals? ... to do DMA operations, to manage SPI/I2C peripherals, to manage PWM ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

For instance my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

Also see [Minimal GPIO access](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Misc_minimal_gpio).

> This C code has a minimal set of functions needed to control the GPIO
>   and other Broadcom peripherals. The program requires root privileges
>   to run. See Tiny GPIO access for an alternative which controls the
>   GPIO (but not the other peripherals) and does not require root access.

Comment: `hardware timed PWM on all of GPIO 0-31` ... this is what I was trying to do ... on at least 8 GPIOs. Thank you!